# Printer List not showing correctly

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, printing

I use this code for the get printers

```
public IActionResult Details(int id)
{
        PrinterSettings.StringCollection printers = PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters;

        ViewBag.Printers = printers;

        return Ok();
 }
```

When i debugged the code i see this is worked. I get my local printers.

But then i deploy this code to the hosting. This time click the button from the website. i dont get my local printers.

i think reason is the the operation system security. OS not allowed for this operation. If this is true can i fix these in the computers. This operation use the just 3 computers. i have access to these computers.

NOTE: This is .net MVC Project. i send this printer list to front (selectbox)

Comment: you can't get it thru the web browser. you'll have to share the printers in windows

Comment: @DanielA.White how can i do this ?

Comment: You can't get the printers from the client, because JavaScript doesn't have this capability (or, rather, Web browsers don't provide this through JS), and if you do it on the server you'll get the printers the server has access to. So, it's impossible. But why do you want a list of printers in a web page anyway?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel i want user select printer name from selectbox and click the button the file printed automatically. Printed file is the sticky Xprinter paper.

Answer (score 0):

On hosting, if you run the app-pool under Administrator account, then this code *might* work.

Again, this will list all the printers on the **Server**.